# How do I transfer maps from a Mac to my PC?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently got a PC better suited for games than my MacBook Air.  In the process, my maps will not show up in the single player map selection menu.

I copied all of the data onto a flash drive, copied it onto the PC, installed Minecraft.  The maps appear in the folders but not in-game!

No files are zipped!

What can I do to get these maps working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the maps are in this folder:

Yourname>appdata>roaming>.minecraft>saves.

P.S. I also play minecraft and have created a .minecraft library for ease of access, but it is entirely up to you if you want to do this.

P.P.S. The dot in .minecraft is important, it is not a mistake. If you are having trouble finding the folder, you can also search for it but from my experience, it takes a little time.

Hope this helps,
DM01131

Answer (score 0):

Strange answer..

My Minecraft installer installed on my Administrator account against my will (I was using another account).  Somehow the game was running from the administrator account.  I don't even know how that is possible, but I managed to get a map in the administrator's folder and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when transferred a file from Mac OS and Windows, a folder or 2 is created near the front of the address. You need to check a normal path for a world you created on there, to see what is wrong on the transferred files. Sometimes it will be

```
Minecraft > Saves > WORLDFOLDER
```

on Mac, but after transfer it is

```
.minecraft > saves > MACOS > WORLDFOLDER
```